# PHP to csv semi-colon issue

Tags: php

I have the following `$data` array:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => '37899810;214214;01;5083;;',
    (int) 1 => '37899810;214215;01;19966;;',
    (int) 2 => '37899810;54654;01;35691;;',
    (int) 3 => '37899810;769;01;52016;;'
)
```

When I try to echo it as csv in the following way:

```
foreach($data as $row):
    echo $row."\n";
endforeach;
```

For each and every row, the semi-colons are escaped and integers are put into different cells. What I want to get instead, is the whole string, let's say `37899810;214214;01;5083;;` to be placed in one cell, and that the remaining ones would be placed in the other rows, but the strings would just take one cell.

Comment: You could use a double quoted enclosure? `'"37899810;214214;01;5083;;"'`

Comment: What cells? How are they generated?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jack, that was all I needed. Could you please submit it as an answer?

Comment: [No, it doesn't](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f171ccb9aa75db89c3e68b77bf509a9d67321832). Your question is incomplete at best.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=example.csv');
$handle = fopen('php://output', 'r+');
foreach ($data as $row) {
   fputcsv($handle, $row, ';');
}
fclose($handle);
```